# Creating a regular expression in Delphi using TRegEx

Tags: regex, delphi

I am looking to create a regular expression in Delphi XE that will match a number followed by one decimal point, followed by (essentially) an unlimited number of digits.

*Valid examples:*

```
2.334
150.2
0.23
3
```

*Invalid examples:*

```
3..42
4-2.3
e5.64
3 145
```

The decimal point may be optional and integers are also okay.

How would one go about doing this in Delphi using TRegEx?

**Edit:**

This is what I have thus far:

```
enter function CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput(InputtedTerm : TEdit) : boolean;

 var
  RegularExpression : TRegEx;
  Match : TMatch;

 begin
  RegularExpression.Create('[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+');
  Match := RegularExpression.Match(InputtedTerm.Text);
  if Match.Success then
   begin
    ShowMessage('Success.');
   end;

 end;
```

**Edit 2:**

Trying @DavidHeffernan's code:

```
Function CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput(InputtedTerm : TEdit) : boolean;
  var
    RegularExpression : TRegEx;
    Match : TMatch;
  begin
    CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput := true;
    if not RegularExpression.IsMatch(InputtedTerm.Text, '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+') then
      CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput := false;
  end;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Matches#Code_Examples

Comment: Is your question how to write code doing a regex, or are you asking for the proper regex? What have you tried?

Comment: See the edit I have made, above.

Comment: `RegularExpression.Create()` must be `RegularExpression := TRegEx.Create()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to cater for a sign too, to allow for negative numbers. This should do.

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

This won't recognise scientific notation but then you did not ask for that. This returns `True` if the pattern can be found anywhere inside the input text. I don't know your full requirements, but I guess you want to match against the entire input string. Use the `^` and `$` start and end of line anchors for that. And perhaps you want to allow whitespace around the value too:

```
^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\s*$
```

Test for a match like this:

```
TRegEx.IsMatch(Input, '^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\s*$')
```

A demonstration:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.RegularExpressions;

procedure Check(const Input: string);
begin
  Writeln(Input, ' ', TRegEx.IsMatch(Input, '^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\s*$'));
end;

begin
  Check('2.334');
  Check('150.2');
  Check('0.23');
  Check('3');
  Check('3..42');
  Check('4-2.3');
  Check('e5.64');
  Check('3 145');
end.
```

**Output**

```
2.334 TRUE
150.2 TRUE
0.23 TRUE
3 TRUE
3..42 FALSE
4-2.3 FALSE
e5.64 FALSE
3 145 FALSE
```

The reference for Delphi regular expressions is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

And the documentation for the Delphi regular expression class: 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx

---

It would be far easier just to call `TryStrToFloat`.

Comment: Also you could look for appearance of '.' for more then twice. Like    AnsiPos('.', Copy(string, AnsiPos('.', string )+1, length(string)); that is in case you don't have letters. :)

Comment: @CiucaS the period can match 0 or 1 times only.

Comment: he postat an example '3..42' I was referring to it.

Comment: @CiucaS that won't match that pattern

Comment: Oh, it's you. You are still trying to write an expression parser? You won't get far with regex.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I scrapped that idea, I am just getting the user to enter coefficients now as strings that I verify using RegEx.

Comment: The JCL expression evaluator is a single unit. I've no clue why you would not use it. Use `TryStrToFloat`.

Comment: Anyway, all the regex in the answer are fine. They do different things. If you want to match the entire string, use the final regex.

Comment: Essentially, I'm doing this (quite) large program as part of a school assignment and I have to do as much of the code as possible myself, i.e. without using pre-made units, etc. I get a nice amount of marks for using regular expressions hence my use here.

Comment: You are cheating by getting me to write your regex for you. Can't you do some independent research? I've given you all the links that you need. Concentrate on learning to do it yourself. I'm not meaning to be rude, but learning regex takes time. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is gold dust

Comment: I've found the problem, using TEdit in the function as opposed to a string will cause the function to fail. It seems that a string is the only way to make it work.

Comment: It won't compile if you pass a TEdit. Oi can't debug code I can't see, with error messages I cannot see.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the RegEx. How can one modify it so 0 is invalid but 0.[whatever] is valid?

Comment: The `?` makes the dot optional. Remove the `?`.

Answer (score 3):

I know all the cool kids love RegEx, but imho it is overkill for this sort of problem when a very simple validation routine will do the job (and is far more likely to be comprehensible in months/years to come).

Something along the lines of:

```
function IsValidNumber(s: String): Boolean;
var
  parts: TStringDynArray;
begin
  parts := SplitString(s, '.');
  case Length(parts) of
    1: result := StrToIntDef(s, -1) <> -1;
    2: result :=      (StrToIntDef(parts[0], -1) <> -1)
                 and  (StrToIntDef(parts[1], -1) <> -1);
  else
    result := FALSE;
  end;
end;
```

Having said that, a more general solution may be desirable and as an aside I would mention that in my own code if I had the same requirement I would use my own string template class.

This is essentially a "*regex for mere  mortals*", allowing a simpler process of pattern matching based on variable elements within a string - optionally of an enforced type (int, guid etc) - separated by well-known literal parts.

In this case my class would have solved the problem thus:

```
 if TStringTemplate.Match(['[:int]', '[:int].[:int]'], s) then
```

You supply an array of templates and a candidate string to match against those templates.  The first match 'wins' and TRUE is returned.  If there are no matches then FALSE is returned.  Where a string matches a template you can optionally capture the variable parts into a name/value pair list (a **TStringList** which you must supply).  So, given these calls:

```
 TStringTemplate.Match(['[whole:int]', '[whole:int].[decimal:int]'], '42', list);
 TStringTemplate.Match(['[whole:int]', '[whole:int].[decimal:int]'], '3.14159', list);
```

Then **list** will contain, in each case:

```
[0] whole=42
```

and

```
[0] whole=3
[1] decimal=14159
```

If the variable parts aren't named then the corresponding variables are simply added to the list as values in the order in which they occur in the matched value:

```
 TStringTemplate.Match(['[whole:int]', '[:int].[:int]'], '3.14159', list);
```

Will yield the list:

```
[0] 3
[1] 14159
```

Unfortunately I cannot currently publish this class as it is in turn dependent upon my own string library which is currently undergoing a major overhaul, prior to release in my github repo.  But if you are interested I will let you know when it's ready (v. soon) or you can just ["watch" my repo](https://github.com/deltics/delphi.libs).

Comment: I'm not convinced that inventing non-standard alternatives to regex is such a great idea. If pattern matching is what you want, what's so bad about regex? In this case a call to `TryStrToFloat` is by some distance the best approach though.

Comment: w.r.t TryStrToFloat(), the 'specification' seems to rule out many inputs that are valid floats (scientific notation, signed values).  That may be an oversight in the 'spec', but it *is* the spec.  My StringTemplate class doesn't set out to be an alternative to regex, it solves only a subset of the problems that regex solves, but does so far more simply (imho).  i.e. in a way that is comprehensible to anyone, not only those who live, eat and breath regex cryptoglyphics (many of whom often screw up their regex anyway, which in itself says a lot about regex imho).

Comment: I can't comprehend your pattern matching language. I do understand regex though. I already know regex. That's one advantage of a standard. And yes, I guess the spec is imprecise because the asker is still working it, this being a school project. By the way, I'm really enjoying your recent contributions to SO. I like the work you've been doing here. Lots of explanation and reasoning and prose and not so much, "try this code" as we sometimes see here.

Answer (score 0):

What about that regular expression?

```
-?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Also if you want to validate floating numbers with mantissa, use that:

```
-?\d+([\.|e\-]+\d+)?
```

Works well both for 3.14, -3.14, -3e14, 3e-14, -3e-14. And works for error string like 3.e-14.

Therefore that is more advanced expression that works without error:

```
-?\d*\.?\d+([eE]\-?\d+)?
```